# Transcendental numbers in the p-adic rationals $\mathbb Q_p$

Tags: galois-theory, p-adic-analysis, p-adic-numbers

I know that there are uncountably infinite transcendentals over $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb Q_p$. What i want to ask is if there is a way to determine whether a transcendental over $\mathbb Q$  lays in the field $\mathbb Q_p$. Thank you!

Comment: Being trascendental always refers to an inclusion, right? I don't understand your question.

Comment: What is your question supposed to mean?  By definition, if $E/K$ and $F/K$ are both purely transcendental with transcendence degree $1$, then $E$ is isomorphic to $F$ as a $K$-extension.

Comment: First you need to say what it means.  I know what it means for an element of $\mathbb Q_p$ to be transcendental (over $\mathbb Q$).  But what is "a transcendental over $\mathbb Q$" with no mention of a larger field?

Comment: One possible misconception here is that $\mathbf Q_p$ is naturally a subfield of $\mathbf R$ (or $\mathbf C$) and the question is asking something like "how to tell if a transcendental real is in $\mathbf Q_p$". I could be completely wrong, of course.

Comment: Does it make sense to ask whether $\pi$ is in $\mathbb Q_p$?

Comment: @GeraldEdgar, yes. the larger field would be the complex field

Comment: @ArtiePrendergast-Smith,yes the larger field is $\mathbb C$.

Comment: First, this is not the right level question for this site... but it is an interesting and deceptive sort of issue. I read somewhere that, for example, Hensel marred his own reputation by giving an irremediably flawed proof that $\pi$ is irrational by accidentally assuming that a sequence of rational numbers that is Cauchy in $\mathbb R$ _and_ in $\mathbb Q_p$ has a limit that is "the same" in both, in some alleged sense... which is not the case.

Comment: @paulgarrett, so should i use the same tactic?do you know where i can find this proof?

Comment: But the idea of proving $\pi$ is transcendental (or whatever) in $\mathbb R$ by proving that a Cauchy sequence of rationals converging to it both in the reals and in the $p$-adics is transcendental in the $p$-adics simply does _not_ prove the transcendence of its limit in the reals. The tactic fails, is the point. It's catchy, and suggestive, but fails. :)

Comment: It seems to me that a question that makes more sense (but that I expect is hopeless) is asking whether or not a given element of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$. Otherwise, the question asked by Gerald and further developed by Paul is very much to the point.

Comment: It does not make sense to ask if $\pi$ is in $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Even in situations where you are tempted to say a certain real number is in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ (e.g. $\sum p^n/n!$ converges $p$-adically and defines a transcendental number) it is not correct as there is no canonical way to embed $\mathbb{Q}_p$ in $\mathbb{C}$. In particular, my parenthetical number is not $e^p$ in any meaningful way. This question is based on a misunderstanding of the definitions and should be closed.

Comment: In fact, it is ambiguous even for algebraics.  If $p$ is such that $2$ has two square-roots in $\mathbb Q_p$, there is no canonical way to specify which of them is $\sqrt{2}$ and which is $-\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: It seems to me that one way to turn the question into a meaningful one (although may be uninteresting to the OP) is to ask whether there exists an explicit way to tell whether an element of $\mathbb{C}_p$ (or of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ or of any field $K\supseteq\mathbb{Q}_p$) which is trascendental over $\mathbb{Q}$ is already in $\mathbb{Q}_p$: like testing whether a trascendental complex number is real but in the $p$-adic world. If $K/\mathbb{Q}_p$ is not Galois, it seems interesting.